# Bokeh not producing figure after adding patches over gmap

Tags: python, gis, bokeh, geopandas

The following code, where testdata.json is https://pastebin.com/tCZQGMsK will produce a figure with patches, but when I try to make the exact same patches over a gmap, the patches don't show up.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import json
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, GMapOptions, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import gmap, figure


file = gpd.read_file("testdata.json")
j = json.loads(file.to_json())
data = json.dumps(j)
data_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = data)

output_notebook()
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=30.2861, lng=-97.7394, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)

#this produces a figure
fig = figure()
fig.patches('xs','ys', source = data_source,
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)

#there are no patches on this
plot = gmap("i keep posting this with my api key...", map_options, title = "test", tools="hover")

plot.patches('xs','ys', source = data_source,
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)
show(plot)
output_file("gmap.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine for me - make sure that your coordinates and your color mapper are correct. Check also if there are any errors in the JavaScript console or Python output.

Regarding the plot object not having a patches function - that's because you're using a plot model explicitly as opposed to using a higher level API. See the example below.

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=30.2861, lng=-97.7394, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)

p = gmap(%YOUR_API_KEY%, map_options, title="Austin")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lats=[[30.29, 30.20, 30.29]],
                                    lons=[[-97.70, -97.74, -97.78]]))

p.patches(xs="lons", ys="lats", fill_alpha=0.8, source=source)

show(p)
```

---

### An update, given that you have edited your question.

You don't need `geopandas` and `json`, just read the file as is and pass it to the data source:

```py
with open("testdata.json") as file:
    data_source = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=file.read())
```

But the more important thing is that you have bad data. Check out the coordinates in your JSON. It has numbers like `3538864.641298605`, which is clearly neither latitude nor longitude. And that's exactly why you don't see anything on GMap.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eugene! I've made the changes, but it still produces an empty figure for some reason! I thought it might be an error when I add patches from a GeoJSONDataSource, but when I create a figure from scratch and add two different geojsondatasources, it doesn't error and produces a figure with these two geojsons overlaid over eachother. If I simply change the name of the figure being modified (from tractfigure to mapplot) and don't modify the patch function, my gmap goes back to producing nothing. I'm going to try to see if I can replicate this with a smaller dataset.

Comment: Maybe. I cannot really tell you anything without a minimal reproducible example that includes a data sample.

Comment: Turns out that actually does work... i'll update you when i can actually reproduce the error

Comment: okay I just wrote over the question. the code should reproduce the error

Comment: Also, something interesting I found is that adding "file = file.to_crs("EPSG:900913")" right after the geopandas import will go back to not producing a map (as opposed to producing a map with no points). Changing that to ESPG:4326 will produce again produce a map with no patches on it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. For some reason, using the data https://pastebin.com/c31KUZBZ which has data points 0-19 will produce a map, but using the data https://pastebin.com/BwcBZPmr will not. I think maybe after 20 patches on a gmap bokeh gives up? It's odd because my entire dataset (200-300) can be plotted on a normal bokeh figure.

Comment: It's a bug with `MultiPolygon`, I have created https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10193

Comment: Is there any way to work around this bug or do I just have to wait til its fixed?

Comment: I imagine you could manually massage the data so every `MultiPolygon` is replaced with a set of regular `Polygon` features.